# Removing the pictures outside the contour area

Tags: python, jupyter, contour, roi

I am trying to remove the image that is not contoured. Are there any suggestions on how to achieve them? Below is my code for the contour

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
im = cv2.imread('after.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

largest_area = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]
mask = np.zeros(im.shape, np.uint8)

cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.drawContours(imgray, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

image_remainder = cv2.bitwise_and(im, 255 - mask)

#cv2.imshow('Image', im)
cv2.imshow('Image GRAY', imgray)
cv2.imshow('extract', image_remainder)
#cv2.imwrite("remainder.png", image_remainder)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Is there a way to only get the skin inside the contour, hope you can help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last parameter of the `cv2.drawContours()` function to `-1`

```
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.drawContours(imgray, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```